# How to get the deb package located directory in preinst

Tags: deb, dpkg, dpkg-buildpackage

I am creating a .deb package that would run a shell script as preinst.

The shell script needs some input files, which would be available at where I have the .deb package, as below.

```
Package_located_directory $ >
         mydebpackage.deb
         inputfile1
         inputfile2
```

I would just transfer all the files to the different machine at any location and install it with dpkg -i mydebpackage.deb

I tried using pwd in the preinst to get the current deb file located directory.

So, I can get the path of the inputfiles from the preinst script.

But if I run `pwd` from preinst , it is giving me / instead of the package located directory.

Also I tried passing pwd from the PIPE to achieve this, as below,

```
   pwd | dpkg -i mydebpackage.deb
```

But I do not want to depend on the user input for the path.

Please guide me for getting the current deb package located directory path from inside of preinst script.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use `postinst` and modify the file on your system.
for example : Modify the file /etc/test/test.txt in postinst file